# C# Date Parse non standard date format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Get a strange date format from web service and am wondering how to parse it to a normal datetime.

Service result: `01-05T09:55` (**MM-dd Time**)

As this string does not have year it fails in `DateTime.Parse`.

Any ideas how to get it to the current year without manipulating it with string functions?

Comment: Use `ParseExact` and specify the format

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact` where you can provide the format.

Comment: What date does it represent (is the year 2017? 2018? something else)?

Comment: Its 2017 but if the date was 25-12T00:00 it would be 2017 that's the issue.  Also ParseExact does not parse this format .

Comment: `Also ParseExact does not parse this format` - If you give it the correct format, yes it does, that's the whole point of `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and provide the format:

```
string source = "01-05T09:55";

// 5 Jan 2017 (current year) 9:55
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "M-d'T'H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: But to the 3rd party that is next year.

Comment: @AliK That's unrelated to your immediate issue. You will have to handle any logical assumptions yourself.

Comment: Yes i guess I will

Comment: I think it would be _better_ to use `MM`, `dd`, `HH` (or even `mm`?) since their values have leading zeros.

Comment: @Soner Gönül: we have just *one* example (which - you are quite right - has leading zeroes and technically correspods to `MM-dd'T'HH:mm` format); however `M-d'T'H:m` format accepts values with or without leading zeroes - and I've put it in order to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format;

```
var date = "01-05T09:55";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-ddTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Here is a working example;

https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2nz1N